# Boot problem Ubuntu 18.04 UID 121

Tags: boot

My computer crash after i select to boot Ubuntu 18.04, i can acces Windows 10 without problems. I don't know much about programming so it's strange, i don't change anything, but from one day to a other this started to happen.

/Dev/sda6:recovery journal

/dev/sda6:clean, 316942/3760120 files, 14317183/150205544 blocks

[Ok] started snappy daemon.

```
    Starting wait until snape is fully seeded...
```

[Ok] started wait until snape is fully seeded.

[Ok] created slice User Slice of NameOfUser.

```
    Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
```

[Ok] Started sesión 1 of User NameOfUser.

[Ok] Started User Manager for UID 1000.

[Ok] Created slice User Slice of gdm.

```
    Starting User Manager for UID 121...
```

[Ok] Started Session c1 of User gdm.

[Ok] Started User Manager for UID 121.

[Ok] Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.

[Ok] Removed slice User Slice of NameOfUser.

```
    Stoppimg User Manager for UID 121...
```

[Ok] Started Session C2 of User gdm.

```
    Starting User Manager for UID 121...
```

[Ok] Started User Manager for UID 121.

_