# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck during boot with "Started User Manager for UID ..."

Tags: boot, grub2, gnome, gdm, wayland

Hello everybody out there using Ubuntu,

Booting Ubuntu 18.04 on a ThinkPad X230t (with Coreboot BIOS) used to work fine, but now it stops with the message

```
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Created slice User Slice of user.
[      ] Started User Manager for UID 1000...
[  OK  ] Started Session 1 of user user.
[  OK  ] Started User Manager for UID 1000.
```

Related issues have been reported on

- [Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on booting with message "started user manager for uid 120" on Asus 1015PX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037922/ubuntu-18-04-hangs-on-booting-with-message-started-user-manager-for-uid-120-on)
- [Ubuntu 18.04- Stuck on 'Started User Manager for UID 121...'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207775/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-on-started-user-manager-for-uid-121?rq=1) (caused by installation of MATLAB)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2440723 and
- [Boot problem Ubuntu 18.04 UID 121](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175342/boot-problem-ubuntu-18-04-uid-121)

Among the recommended solutions were to check for free disk space (there is plenty of it in my case), as well as uncommenting the line

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, which didn't fix the issue.

I assumed it could be a problem with GNOME Display Manager (`gdm3`) and ran

```
systemctl restart gdm
```

after having booted into recovery mode.
Indeed, I only get a black screen after running this command.

Therefore, I installed `lightdm` as a replacement for `gdm3` hoping it would fix the issue.
`lightdm` seems to try to start some graphical environment, but still fails: I see a black screen.

There is a message in `/var/log/kern.log`

```
EDD information not available.
```

but I'm not sure whether this is a problem.

Does anyone know which additional diagnostics I could run to pin down the problem?

I should mention that I can boot into recovery mode perfectly fine (even with graphics enabled).

When checking the graphics driver in recovery mode, `llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)` is indicated, which could be part of the problem: ThinkPad X230 actually has an i7 processor with onboard Intel HD Graphics.
Therefore, I would assume the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` to be already installed by default, but

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

gives me

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing `xserver-xorg-core` and `xserver-xorg` brought me closer to a solution:
I could boot an older kernel to X and now get `Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)` as graphics.

Comment: How did you check the available disk space? What does plenty mean?

Comment: Dear David, running `df -h` shows me more than 3 TB free space for `/dev/sda2`.

Comment: gparted will give more info on partitions I think.

Comment: Thanks again. gparted indicates `/dev/sda1` as the partition on which grub is located. I guess this should be the normal configuration. A bit strange is the size of `1.00 MiB` indicated by gparted for this partition: I think it should actually be larger.